# Why did/would Obi-Wan say that Yoda trained him?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi

Reading [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16090/why-did-luke-name-his-son-ben-and-not-obi-wan) question and [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13927/was-obi-wan-ever-taught-by-yoda) one, I noticed that Obi-Wan says twice that Yoda trained him.

> Yoda: [Looking away from Luke] I cannot teach him. The boy has no patience.
>
> Obi-Wan: [voice-over] He will learn patience.
>
> Yoda: Much anger in him... like his father.
>
> Obi-Wan: [voice] Was I any different when **you taught me?**

Emphasis mine.

In the second question's answers, we learn that Yoda may have taught Ben a little bit. Ok, so this quote makes sense. However, I find the lack of sense of this one... disturbing.

> Luke lies face down in the snow, nearly unconscious. Slowly he looks up and sees Ben Kenobi, barely visible through the blowing snow. It is hard to tell if Kenobi is real or a hallucination.
>
> BEN: Luke...Luke.
>
> LUKE: (weakly) Ben?
>
> BEN: You will go to the Dagobah system.
>
> LUKE: Dagobah system?
>
> BEN: There you will learn from Yoda, **the Jedi Master who instructed me.**
>
> The image of Ben fades, revealing a lone Tauntaun rider approaching from the windswept horizon.
>
> LUKE: (groaning faintly) Ben...Ben.

Emphasis mine again.

Indeed, (teaching in some boot camp once in a while) vs. (years of private training with his master) doesn't look like a victory for boot camp to me.

**The question: Why would Ben tell Luke that Yoda was The Jedi Master who he learned from?**

(Different, thus not duplicate, than *Did Yoda really instructed Ben?*)

Of course, the obvious out-universe reason would be **George Lucas**, but a in-universe would be appreciated. Was hiding Qui-Gon's role in Obi-Wan's training something important?

Comment: Don't forget Qui-Gon died before Obi Wan's training was fully completed ... maybe it played a part.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of the linked question to me.

Comment: Well, I think there could be a psychological component to it. Obi-Wan saying *"My master is dead, but this little green guy is pretty good too"*, would not have the same weight as saying that Yoda trained him and that he was as impatient as Luke but still turned out fine under Yoda's tutelage. Also, what good is mentioning a long dead Jedi? Yoda was still there and thus much more important to Luke. It's also not a lie. Yoda is shown teaching a whole class of Padawans. He most likely taught Obi-Wan an important thing or two, even if Qui-Gon's influence on him was greater.

Comment: Wouldn't Obi-wan have grown up in the academy (as in, taken as a young child)? Then he surely would have been trained by many Jedi before being apprenticed to Qui-Gon, as Sebastian suggests.

Comment: If you say it's really a duplicate, should i delete ?

Comment: After Qui Jon died Yoda took Kenobi under his wing and helped guide his path to mastery.

Comment: @Chad - if you have canon cite for that, should be an asnwer.

Comment: @Chad it seemed to me that after qui-gon died, the only way obi-wan could took anakin as a padawan is that obi-wan became a jedi master, so the council declared him a master

Comment: @Kalissar - Jedi Knights can have padawan learners as well.  As Anakin did with Asoka.

Comment: @DVK - Its in novels...  I do not remember which ones exactly they came out around the time the movies(II-III) did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Wookieepedia,

> As a youngling, Kenobi trained under Grand Master Yoda alongside other Jedi hopefuls of his age...

Also

> His ability to repair machinery and reprogram computers would serve him well in the future, but because of his ability to learn quickly, Kenobi **became arrogant and was often impatient**. Under the careful guidance of Master Yoda, however, Kenobi became more humble and reserved.

Emphasis mine.  Both quotes can be found here:
[Obi-Wan Kenobi entry on Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Obi-wan)

Comment: Does Wookiepedia have a reference to back those 2 up?

Comment: +1; in ep2 we see Yoda instructing a class of younglings.

Comment: Yoda (and other Jedi masters) trained the students. Obi Wan was supposedly trained by Yoda when he was a student. The moment when he became an apprentice he was tied to Qui-Gon as his master to instruct him.